# How can I edit desktop shortcuts on Kubuntu 15.10?

Tags: kubuntu, 15.10, shortcuts, plasma-5

How can I edit desktop shortcuts on Kubuntu 15.10 ? I mean properties. The command at least. If I right click the desktop shortcut and go to icon settings, there is a keyboard shortcut, which can be handy, but that's all there is. Of course I may find the particular *.desktop file on disk and edit it, but I mean the user-friendly graphical way.

Comment: I have not found such a way yet. There are probably some external tools that allow you to modify these files, but I haven't ever used any of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I need to edit shortcuts I normally open a text editor (Geany or Gedit in my case, but perhaps not yours) and then do a File | Open and go to the folder where they are stored, presumably the Desktop in your case. The files should have a .desktop extension. The content looks a bit like a properties file and you can make the changes you want.

Answer (score 1):

1. unlock ur *Mini-Programms*
2. right-click on the K-Icon in the Deskbar
3. select "change Applications" (not sure if the english term is correctly translate). Then K-Menu-editor opens and u can change things. U need to save any changes. Be careful. Thats the graphical way u asked for.

U can also place your own .desktop files into the directory */home/~/.local/share/applications/* they should get preferenced then against the ones that reside in */usr/share/applications/* there u would actually need super-user rights for editing & storing them.

In KDE-Environment u would use `kdesudo kate` as editor for root.  If you are not familiar with this it's a good help to take screencopy with Ksnapshot before changing anything. Another tip is, to read the man-page of the programm, e.g. `man kpat` pgdown/pgup & Q to finish – Sometimes I do like playing Klondike, so I've created a starter *KPat-Klondike*. The man-page tells how to start it wt an option: `kpat --gametype klondike` U can try this from the terminal firstly. Since you'll get a feedback on any errors there.

Any more Questions? Keep on asking ;-)

Another advice is also to set up a raw installation of your choice-distro in VirtualBox and test things there. This is called "Testing-Environment". I speak from my own experience - the knowledge curve will speed up nicely that way. Have fun Kubuntuing!